# Add one month to gmdate using current format

Tags: php, html, date, datetime

Hello I have the following php code:

```
$date = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"); /*Format: '2015-05-24T00:00:00Z'*/
```

How would I simply add 1 month to the above date while keeping the same format?

I tried a few things that lead to nowhere, I am sure there should be a way of doing it that I can't seem to find.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try below:

```
$date = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime("+1 month"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$date = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime('+ 1 MONTH'));
echo $date;
```

It will add one month to the date.